# New post status for custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, post-status

I have a custom post type `recipes`. I am using a cron script to automatically aggregate news into the database.

It is currently being imported and saved as 'Pending Review'. Is it possible to create another post status called `Aggregated` which will list all of the aggregated news to be published?

I tried using the `register_post_status` function, however this didn't seem to work:

```
function custom_post_status(){
    register_post_status( 'aggregated', array(
        'label'                     => _x( 'Aggregated', 'recipes' ),
        'public'                    => false,
        'exclude_from_search'       => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Aggregated <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Aggregated <span class="count">(%s)</span>' ),
    ) );
}
add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_status' );
```

Thanks for help with this.

Comment: I think the code is right. Maybe you have this source in a other function to call this. When run the add_action()?

Comment: Could you please explain your answer in more details? thanks!

Comment: Is the add_action( 'init' inside a class or function, there you call about a other hook. It is possible, that you start this to lat and the hook init can nor fired.

Comment: How did you resolve this issue? I have exactly the same problem now. I like to add the new custom status to the drop down list of the custom-post admin area, that allows the user to select (Pendig Reveiw, Draft, NEW_CUSTOM_STATUS) from the list of Stati...

Answer (score 15):

There is a great Step by Step description on how to do that here https://www.jclabs.co.uk/create-custom-post-status-in-wordpress-using-register_post_status/

To add your custom post status to the drop-down menue, just add the following to your themes function script:

```
add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'jc_append_post_status_list');
function jc_append_post_status_list(){
 global $post;
 $complete = '';
 $label = '';
 if($post->post_type == 'recipes'){
      if($post->post_status == 'aggregated'){
           $complete = ' selected=\"selected\"';
           $label = '<span id=\"post-status-display\"> Aggregated</span>';
      }
      echo '
      <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"aggregated\" '.$complete.'>Aggregated</option>");
           $(".misc-pub-section label").append("'.$label.'");
      });
      </script>
      ';
  }
}
```

With this you have your custom post status up and running in 5 min, saved me a bunch of time!

Comment: Link is broken. Here's the [most recent version on archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20181026023402/http://jamescollings.co.uk/blog/wordpress-create-custom-post-status/).

Comment: @rinogo thanks man, switched to the archive.org link you provided

Comment: Here is an updated link to the article on James Collings new website: https://www.jclabs.co.uk/create-custom-post-status-in-wordpress-using-register_post_status/

Comment: Thanks @joehanna i updated the link :)

Answer (score 10):

Your code should be sound, and should add the desired status to the $wp_post_statuses global array.

If you are expecting it to show up in the admin drop-down, however, this is an ongoing issue:
https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12706

Answer (score 9):

Register a post status "aggregated" for custom post type "recipes" :

```
register_post_status( 'aggregated', array(
                    'label'                     => _x( 'Aggregated ', 'post status label', 'plugin-domain' ),
                    'public'                    => true,
                    'label_count'               => _n_noop( 'Aggregated s <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Aggregated s <span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'plugin-domain' ),
                    'post_type'                 => array( 'recipes' ), // Define one or more post types the status can be applied to.
                    'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
                    'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
                    'show_in_metabox_dropdown'  => true,
                    'show_in_inline_dropdown'   => true,
                    'dashicon'                  => 'dashicons-businessman',
                ) );
```

In the "recipes" custom  post edit screen's publish metabox, adding the custom post status in the dropdown and change the "Save Draft" button label if the selected post status is "aggregated" :

```
add_action('admin_footer-post.php',function(){

    global $post;
    $complete = '';
    $label = '';

    if($post->post_type == 'recipes') {

        if ( $post->post_status == 'aggregated' ) {
            $complete = ' selected=\"selected\"';
            $label    = 'Aggregated';
        }

        $script = <<<SD

 
       jQuery(document).ready(function($){
           $("select#post_status").append("<option value=\"aggregated\" '.$complete.'>Aggregated</option>");
           
           if( "{$post->post_status}" == "aggregated" ){
                $("span#post-status-display").html("$label");
                $("input#save-post").val("Save Aggregated");
           }
           var jSelect = $("select#post_status");
                
           $("a.save-post-status").on("click", function(){
                
                if( jSelect.val() == "aggregated" ){
                    
                    $("input#save-post").val("Save Aggregated");
                }
           });
      });
     

SD;

        echo '<script type="text/javascript">' . $script . '</script>';
    }

});
```

Add the custom post status in the quick edit screen of the custom post admin grid :

```
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php',function() {
    global $post;
    if( $post->post_status == 'recipes' ) {
        echo "<script>
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
        jQuery( 'select[name=\"_status\"]' ).append( '<option value=\"aggregated\">Aggregated</option>' );
    });
    </script>";
    }
});
```

Display the custom post status total in the custom post admin grid :

```
add_filter( 'display_post_states', function( $statuses ) {
    global $post;

    if( $post->post_type == 'recipes') {
        if ( get_query_var( 'post_status' ) != 'aggregated' ) { // not for pages with all posts of this status
            if ( $post->post_status == 'aggregated' ) {
                return array( 'Aggregated' );
            }
        }
    }
    return $statuses;
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. However, it still misses the custom post status in the bulk post edit status dropdown.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working code for WP 6.2 without using JQuery

// 1. Register a post status "aggregated"

```
add_action('init', 'add_custom_post_status');
function add_custom_post_status()
{
    register_post_status('aggregated', array(
        'label'                     => _x('Aggregated', 'recipes'),
        'public'                    => true,
        'show_in_admin_all_list'    => true,
        'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
        'label_count'               => _n_noop('Aggregated<span class="count">(%s)</span>', 'Aggregated <span class="count">(%s)</span>'),
    ));
}
```

// 2. In the post edit screen: adding the custom post status in the dropdown

```
add_action('admin_footer-post.php', 'append_post_status_list');
function append_post_status_list()
{
    global $post;

    if ($post->post_type != 'recipes') {
        return;
    }

    $selected = 'false';
    $setStatus = '';
    if ($post->post_status == 'aggregated') {
        $selected = 'true';
        $setStatus = 'document.getElementById("post-status-display").innerHTML = "Aggregated";';
    }
    echo '
          <script>
            document.getElementById("post_status").appendChild(new Option("Aggregated", "aggregated", ' . $selected . '));
            ' . $setStatus . '
          </script>
          ';
}
```

// 3. In the quick edit screen (list page): adding the custom post status in the dropdown

```
add_action('admin_footer-edit.php', function () {    
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type != 'recipes') {
        return;
    }

    echo '
    <script>
        document.querySelectorAll("select[name=\"_status\"]").forEach((s) => {
            s.appendChild(new Option("Aggregated", "aggregated"));
        });
    </script>';
});
```