# How to stop post status from reverting to Published?

Tags: custom-post-types, save-post, post-status

I have custom post types and custom statuses registered. The post status is updated from a custom drop down box that I have inserted into a metabox on the edit post screen.

It works fine, however whenever I update a post or create a new post and set the custom post status from the dropdown, it resets back to "Published".

It seems that if either the Publish button is pressed when creating a post, or the Update button is pressed when editing the post status always defaults to published.

PS: I used the codes from here: [New post status for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89351/new-post-status-for-custom-post-type)

Comment: Do you have a "Save Draft" button? Because until I publish a new post, I click the "Save Draft" button only.

Comment: Yes, but even after clicking "Save Draft" then i publish the post, the post status won't save and just reverts back to "Published". I guess the problem is because the button only appears as "Publish" not "Update". So whenever i create a new post or update an existing one, the custom post status reverts back the Published instead of the selected custom post status.