# register_post_status invisible but searchable

Tags: plugins, customization, export

I need to "hide" some old posts from the I decided to go with a custom post status to keep them hidden but available at a later time (keeps the admin cleaner..)
BUT :)

I would like to have the posts with this status searchable but not available with the other filter-links like this ("Archived (2)") should not be in this list...

*All (97) | Published (95) | Drafts (12) | Archived (2) |Private (2) | Trash (1)|*

I register the post status with these parameters...

```
'public' => false,
'internal' =>true,
'exclude_from_search' => false,
'show_in_admin_all_list' => false,
'show_in_admin_status_list' => true,
```

But with these settings, the menu element is visible, and if I do

```
'show_in_admin_status_list' => false,
```

The posts with "archive" status is not searchable.

I'm using a modified version from this answer (see "PostStatusExtender" )
(changed name and post type)

[New post status for custom post type](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89351/new-post-status-for-custom-post-type)

Any ideas how to solve this one?

Comment: What do you mean by "searchable"?

Comment: Searchable in admin (using the search field to the right above the post list).
These posts should only be available in admin - but not in a "statustype" list as I tried to describe in my original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter your admin query with `pre_get_posts` filter.

```
function wpse_306361_admin_search($query) {
    if(is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {
        $query->set('post_status', array('publish', 'draft', 'what-you-want', 'your_custom_status'));
    }
    return query;
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'wpse_306361_admin_search', 10, 1);
```

It will check if query is in admin, if it's main query and if it's a search query.

If it's only for a `post_type`, don't forget to add a condition in your `if` statement.

`pre_get_posts` on codex : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts

Comment: For some reason, the $query->is_admin() did not work, even if it shows "true" in the dump  (checked $query by dumping it to error_log).
I changed that part of the if statement to "is_admin()" . 
And the post_statuses changed to my prefs.
And voilá. It works :)
Thank you!

Comment: My bad for `$query->is_admin()`, you're right ! `is_admin()` must be use here instead of `$query->is_admin()`